# Coordinate system doesn't seem to match between Playground and iOS Device/Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, scenekit

I've been trying to wrap my head around all the goodness in Xcode 6 and iOS 8 over the last couple of days. I'm currently working with SceneKit to get a feel for what it can do.

I'm trying to build a visual grid to make placing objects in the scene a bit easier.

The Playground displays how I expect it to, but the Simulator/Device does not. I'm not sure if it's a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong.

I have the following code:

```
for index in -20..20 {
  let i   = CFloat(index)
  let neg = i - 20
  let pos = i + 20

  var lat = [
    SCNVector3Make(neg, 0, i),
    SCNVector3Make(pos, 0, i)
  ]
  var lng = [
    SCNVector3Make(i, 0, neg),
    SCNVector3Make(i, 0, pos)
  ]

  var indices: CInt[] = [0, 1]

  let latSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices:&lat, count:2)
  let lngSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices:&lng, count:2)
  let indexData = NSData(bytes:indices, length:sizeof(CInt) * countElements(indices))
  let element = SCNGeometryElement(data:indexData, primitiveType:SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.Line, primitiveCount:2, bytesPerIndex:sizeof(CInt))
  let latLine = SCNGeometry(sources:[latSource], elements:[element])
  let lngLine = SCNGeometry(sources:[lngSource], elements:[element])

  let latLineNode = SCNNode(geometry:latLine)
  let lngLineNode = SCNNode(geometry:lngLine)

  scene.rootNode.addChildNode(latLineNode)
  scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lngLineNode)
}
```

In a Playground the second line is `let i = CGFloat(index)`, but other than that the code is identical between the Playground and the iOS Xcode 6 project I have.

In the Playground, I get the grid I'm after. In the Simulator and on the Device, however, I get garbage. No matter how I change the `SCNVector3Make` calls I can't get the grid to display properly in iOS or the Simulator.

It should also be noted that what is displayed in the Simulator and on the device is identical.

I tried adding a box to the scene also. When I used an `SCNBox` it displays correctly - though much bigger than it should. When I use custom geometry (that works correctly in the Playground), however, the box dimensions are way off. It looks more like a wall than a cube.

I tried to include screenshots to show what I'm seeing, but apparently I need at least 10 reputation points to post images, sorry.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

To answer the commenter's question below (*regarding how I initialize the scene*):

In the project (*that runs in the Simulator/Device*) this is how I get it:

```
let scene = SCNScene()
let sceneView = SCNView(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
// Build up grid
sceneView.scene = scene
self.view = sceneView
```

In the Playground, I do this:

```
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
XCPShowView("The Scene View", sceneView)
// Build up grid
```

**UPDATE 2**

I created an OSX app, modified the generated GameViewController code to generate the same structures and everything worked as expected. I didn't update the box's color to be red, and the positioning of the cube and camera is a bit different in the OSX app.

Now that I have enough points, I will add images showing the what I'm seeing.

*Also of note* I tried this on both Xcode Beta 2 & 3 - the results were identical.

**What I see in the Playground**

[image]

**What I see in the OSX app**

[image]

**What I see in the iOS Simulator**

[image]

I removed iOS 8 from by phone and iPad, so i don't have any screen shots from those - but they look identical to the Simulator.

I'll be filing a bug report for this through Apple.

**UPDATE 3**

I have created repos for these projects so anyone who's interested can take a look (maybe there's something I'm not aware of that I'm doing wrong):

[Playground project](https://github.com/bsgbryan/SceneKitDemo-Playground)

[OSX project](https://github.com/bsgbryan/SceneKitDemo-OSX)

[iOS project](https://github.com/bsgbryan/SceneKitDemo-iOS)

Please let me know if you see anything I'm doing wrong or how I could be doing things better!

**Thanks for your help everyone!**

Comment: How is the reference to scene initialized in the playground? The root node of the scene in your playground probably has a different coordinate system than on the device and simulator..

Comment: Also, remember that Swift, Xcode 6, Playgrounds, etc. Are still in beta, so things can change or have bugs. If the documentation says the coordinate systems should be the same then you can file a bug report for it :)

Comment: Your playground code is OS X (I can tell since XCPShowView isn't available in iOS playgrounds yet). Are you seeing the same results in an OS X project? Also, I don't see any explicit camera setup in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently playing with UIBezierPath in Playground. Upon posting the question in Apple developer forms, I believe Playground does use a different coordinate system (LLO) than the devices (ULO):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/39277#39277

Here is apple's docs on the two coordinate systems:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW10

Answer (score -1):

you have does not use on first scene (frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds).

In the project (that runs in the Simulator/Device) this is how I get it:

```
let scene = SCNScene()
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
// Build up grid
sceneView.scene = scene
self.view = sceneView
```

In the Playground, I do this:

```
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
XCPShowView("The Scene View", sceneView)
```